# La prefikseca "pri"

Tags: word-formation

[Laŭ PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/afiksecaj_elementoj/rolvortetoj.html#i-r6o) estas uzo kurioza de "pri", kiu ebligas ŝanĝi frazrolon. Ekzemple, eblas per ĝi reordigi la jenan frazon

> X pafas Y-on al Z

tiel ke ĝi iĝu la jena.

> X pripafas Z-on per Y

Tia povo estas tre utila, ĉar estas kelke da okazoj en kiuj estus oportune pasivigi tian verbon, sed tiel ke la objekto *nerekta* unue iĝu rekta kiel en la jena ekzemplo.

> La soldato ĵus pripafita ekkriis al liaj kamaradoj.

Tamen estas (0) verboj kun tro multe da eblaj vortetoj (ekz, "meti", al kiu povas esti "al", "de", "en", "sur", ktp), kaj (1) verboj esence netransitivaj kiuj estas defie pasivigeblaj (precipe "-iĝi" verboj). Do, mi faras du demandojn.

Unue, ĉu eblas klare "pri-igi" verbon, kiel "meti"? "Primeti" sola estus tro ambigua. Ne eblas senpere konstati, kiu el la eblaj vortetoj estas celata.

Due, ĉu entute eblas "pri-igi" verbon, kiel "aliĝi"? Estus tre oportune povi esperante esprimi ekz "joined servers". Mi supozas ke tiuokaze eblas uzi anstataŭe "aniĝi" por ke ĝi estu pli "pri-ig-ebla" (tiel ke ĝi iĝu "prianiĝi[ta]"), sed mi solvon ne povas imagi por alian, kiel ekz "deiĝi".

Konklude, en unu okazo aŭ en ambaŭ, ĉu estas solvo sen[pere de] helpa "oni"?

### Aldonaĵo (2023-07-19)

Mi ĵus rimarkis en PMEG [ion](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/pasivo/bazaj_reguloj.html#i-f2a), kiu la problemon verŝajne solvas iugrade. Anstataŭ diri, ekzemple, "la soldato estis ___pafita" (hipoteze, kun hipoteza vorto "___pafita"), verŝajne eblas diri "estis pafite al la soldato"/"al la soldato estis pafite"/"la soldato, al kiu estis pafite, <bla>"/ktp. Per tio, mi nun povas ĉirkaŭiri duonon de l' problem'.

Comment: Ha, se vi volas montri, ĉu la pafado kaŭzis morton aŭ nur vundon, vi povas precizigi per "mortpafi" resp. "vundpafi". Tio estas pli klara ol uzi la prefiksan "pri-".

Answer (score 3):

Ekzistas tri specoj de verboj en Esperanto.

## sensubjektaj verboj

Ekzistas sensubjektaj verboj en Esperanto. Miascie ĉiuj tiaj malhavas rektan objekton.

- Pluvas sur la kampon.

Pri-prefikso ebligas aldoni subjekton kaj rektan objekton.

- La nuboj pripluvis la kampon.

## sen rekta objekto

Netransitiva verbo estas verbo kun subjekto sed sen rekta objekto. Tia verbo povas havi pri-komplementon, kiu esence montras nerektan objekton.

- Li silentis pri la afero

Se vi kreas pri-prefiksecan verbon de tia verbo, la pri-komplento fariĝas rekta objekto.

- Li prisilentis la aferon.

## kun rekta objekto

Transitiva verbo estas verbo, kiu havas kaj subjekton kaj rektan objekton.

- Li pensis tion pri ŝi.

Notu, ke oni kutime kun la verbo "pensi" la rekta objekto estas subkomprenata "pensoj".

Se vi kreas pri-prefiksecan verbon de tia verbo, la rekta objekto malaperas kaj la pri-komplento fariĝas rekta objekto.

- Li pripensis ŝin.

## ne nur "pri"

Kvankam pri-komplemento estas la plej kutima, eblas krei pri-prefiksecajn verboj de aliaj prepoziciaj komplementoj.

- Ili rabis monon de la homoj. → Ili prirabis la homojn.
- Ili ĵetis ŝtonojn al li. → Ili priĵetis lin per ŝtonoj.
- La luno lumis en la ĉambron. → La luno prilumis la ĉambron.

## senco de pri-prefiksa verbo

Notu, ke la senco de pri-prefikseca verbo estas alia ol sen la prefikso. Oni povas diri, ke pri-prefikseca verbo havas pli grandan amplekson ol tiu de la simpla verbo (ekz. prirabi, prilumi supre). Ofte tio signifas, ke la simpla verbo montras pli malpli unuopan agon, dum la pri-prefikseca verbo montras multoblan aŭ ripetan agon.

- planti rozojn sed priplanti ĝardenon
- ĵeti ŝtonojn sed priĵeti iun per ŝtonoj
- serĉi ies monon sed priserĉi homon

Ĉe kelkaj verboj la pri-prefikseca versio povas aludi konformecon al aludita celo.

- prirespondi ion = doni garantion pri io

## pri-ismo

Kelkaj homoj ne limigas la uzon de la prefikso "pri-" al tiuj du kazoj (”pli granda amplekso” kaj ”konformeco al celo”), sed rigardas, ke oni pli malpli ĉiam povas konstrui verbojn kun prefiksecaj prepozicioj.

- Li donis al mi ringon → *Li aldonis min je ringo* aŭ eĉ *Li pridonis min je ringo*

Tia uzo estas erara. Notu, ke la prefikseca verbo kutime jam havas alian, jam establiĝintan sencon (kp. aldoni supre).

## multaj prefiksoj

Teorie oni povas aldoni plurajn afiksojn al radiko, sed en praktiko la limo kutime estas unu prefikso kaj du postfiksoj. Pliaj afiksoj facile faras vorton nekomprenebla. Ekzemple

- al-iĝ-i

jam havas tri afiksoj (kaj neniu radiko), el kiuj la lasta montras vortklason. Mi ne povas memori vorton kun du prepoziciaj prefiksoj, sed ekzistas kelkaj kun du oficialaj prefiksoj, ekzemple "bogepatroj".

Answer (score 0):

Laŭ mi la uzado de pri kiel subjekto-ŝanĝa prefikso rezultas konfuziga.  Tiu senco estas sufiĉe distanca de la multe pli konata, kiu estas tiu de pri kiel prepozicio, kiu signifas plimalpli "koncerne de" aŭ la angla "about".  "Pri", preskaŭ ĉiam, indikas mensa priokupo aŭ pritrakto por objekto. En la frazo "La nubo pripluvis la kampon" malestas priokupado, ĉar la nubo ne havas menson, eĉ figura-sence.  Tre male al "la flegistino prizorgis la malsanulon".

Persone mi uzus alia prepozicio, prefereble "be", por signifi nuran ŝanĝon de subjekto.  Kiel prepozicio, "be" signifus apartenon al pli ampleksa kunaĵo aŭ propraĵo.  Kiel en "ĉambro be la hospitalo", "ŝtono be domo". "herbaĵo be kampo". "La nubo bepluvis la kampo" signifus do "la nubo pluvis sur io kio estas be la kampo, sur io kio estas parto be (de) la kampo".  En tiu kazo "de" estus ankaŭ prepozicio konfuziga, ĉar sia unua senco estas distanciĝo.

Comment: "Pri" montras tion, kion ago traktas aŭ koncernas. Ĝi ne enhavas ideon de mensa priokupado.